# Writing/Reading strings in binary file-C++

Tags: c++, string, binaryfiles

I searched for a similar post but couldn't find something that could help me.

I' m trying to first write the integer containing the string length of a String and then write the string in the binary file.

However when i read data from the binary file i read integers with value=0 and my strings contain junk.

for example when i type 'asdfgh' for username and 'qwerty100' for password
i get 0,0 for both string lengths and then i read junk from the file.

This is how i write data to the file.

```
std::fstream file;

file.open("filename",std::ios::out | std::ios::binary | std::ios::trunc );

Account x;

x.createAccount();

int usernameLength= x.getusername().size()+1; //+1 for null terminator
int passwordLength=x.getpassword().size()+1;

file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&usernameLength),sizeof(int));
file.write(x.getusername().c_str(),usernameLength);
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&passwordLength),sizeof(int));
file.write(x.getpassword().c_str(),passwordLength);

file.close();
```

Right below in the same function i read the data

```
file.open("filename",std::ios::binary | std::ios::in );

char username[51];
char password[51];

char intBuffer[4];

file.read(intBuffer,sizeof(int));
file.read(username,atoi(intBuffer));
std::cout << atoi(intBuffer) << std::endl;
file.read(intBuffer,sizeof(int));
std::cout << atoi(intBuffer) << std::endl;
file.read(password,atoi(intBuffer));

std::cout << username << std::endl;
std::cout << password << std::endl;

file.close();
```

Comment: The way you read should mirror the way you write.  You didn't write a string representation of the length so there's no reason to try and read it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When reading the data back in you should do something like the following:

```
int result;
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&result), sizeof(int));
```

This will read the bytes straight into the memory of `result` with no implicit conversion to int. This will restore the exact binary pattern written to the file in the first place and thus your original `int` value.

Comment: Note:  beware of endian-ness mismatch problems e.g. if the file was written by a PowerPC machine and read by an Intel machine, or vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&usernameLength),sizeof(int));
```

This writes sizeof(int) bytes from the &usernameLength; which is binary representation of integer and depends on the computer architecture (little endian vs big endian).

```
atoi(intBuffer))
```

This converts ascii to integer and expect the input to contain character representation. e.g. intBuffer = { '1', '2' } - would return 12.

You can try to read it in the same way you have written -

```
*(reinterpret_cast<int *>(&intBuffer))
```

But it can potentially lead to unaligned memory access issues. Better use serialization formats like JSON, which would be helpful to read it in cross-platform ways.