# Writing/reading strings as binary into random accessed file

Tags: c++, stdout, fstream

Simple question: I want to write strings of fixed length into a binary file (that is, as binary), as illustrated in the following snippet.

The writing "looks" fine, but reading from the file doesn't work (compiles and runs without crashed, but doesn't give the expected result).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream out {"out.dat", std::ios::binary};

        //all of length 5
        std::string a[] {{"12345"}, {"6789A"}, {"BCDEF"}};

        //write down strings without \0
        out.write(a[0].c_str(), a[0].length());
        out.write(a[1].c_str(), a[1].length());
        out.write(a[2].c_str(), a[2].length());
    }

    {
        std::ifstream in {"out.dat", std::ios::binary};

        std::string s2 {5, '\0'}; //I can store at least 5 chars
        in.seekg(0 + 2 * 5); //try to read string of index 2
        in.read(&s2[0], 5);

        std::cout << s2 << std::endl; //prints "BC", not "BCDEF"  
    }
}
```

The last line should recover the string "BCDEF", but only "BC" is printed (g++ 10.2.0).

Since the strings have fixed lengths, and that I write that specified number of bytes (chars) into the file, I should be able to recover them with `seekg` (that is, I know where they start, and I can set the input position indicator right there to read).

Note that I don't this this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30645365/writing-reading-strings-in-binary-file-c), since I'm writing chars directly (I don't need to `reinterpret_cast` them).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses the constructor that takes an `std::initializer_list`:

```
std::string s2 {5, '\0'};
```

... and creates a string with 2 characters with the values 5 and 0 (or whatever `\0` is).

It should be `std::string s2 (5, '\0');`

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    {
        std::ofstream out {"out.dat", std::ios::binary};

        //all of length 5
        std::vector<std::string> a{{"12345"}, {"6789A"}, {"BCDEF"}};

        //write down strings without \0
        for(auto& s : a)
            out.write(s.c_str(), s.size());
    }

    {
        std::ifstream in {"out.dat", std::ios::binary};

        std::string s2(5,'\0'); //I can store at least 5 chars
        in.seekg(0 + 2 * 5); //try to read string of index 2
        in.read(s2.data(), 5);

        std::cout << s2 << std::endl; //prints "BC", not "BCDEF"  
    }
}
```

`

Comment: I am... ashamed. It was so simple, and so unrelated to what I tought the problem was... Thanks

Comment: @R.Absil You're welcome! No need to feel ashamed - I had to look at it twice myself. :-)

Comment: Thanks, just did that, with some older questions